# How to centre text vertically and horizontally over a responsive image that's positioned absolute?

Tags: css

I have studied numerous posts and none relate exactly to my own situation and i cannot for the life of me figure this one out. I have a responsive image inside a container that is positioned absolute. There are many of these images on the page, it's a gallery grid of images but each image is a different width and height.

I need a link over  the image to read 'View Project' to be exactly centered vertically and horizontally. I can do this manually by setting the best fit % margin from the top of the image but that's a hell of a lot of code times by all the images on the page which, like i say are all different widths and heights.

My basic code looks like this..

```
<div class="item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
  <a href="link-to-view-project-on-a-different-page.html" title="">
    <img style="width: 100%;" alt="" src="http://placekitten.com/600/400">
    <h2>View Project</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on browser support you can use css transforms with absolute positioning. E.g:

```
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/guyfedwards/pen/KwdxLp)

If browser support is an issue you can use negative margins to achieve a similar result. E.g:

```
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px; /* This value should be half the height of the h2 element */
  margin-left: -5px; /* This value should be half the width of the h2 element */
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response :) This appears to work, i just needed to adjust the margin-top & margin-left (in your 2nd solution) to get the text to centre exactly (for example margin-top was set to -60px and margin-left was set to -30px). Although this works, i have no idea or understanding of why this solution does work. I'm not the best coder! I'm going to try this out now across the other images and check it across different browsers. I'll post back shortly and thanks again.

Comment: The reason you use the negative margins is to offset 50% top and left. For example, when you set `left: 50%` that positions the left side of the element at 50%. The desired effect is normally to have the middle of the element at 50% rather than the left side and so you use a negative margin of half the width/height to pull it back to center. Hope that makes a bit more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xnjy0dar/

Basically you want a wrapper to the image and h2 elements.  Set the wrapper to absolute position in the corner or wherever you want the image to appear.  Set the h2 to position absolute also.  The wrapper will be exactly as large as the image.  Now position the h2 like so.

```
.image1 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.image2 {
    top: 200px;
    left: 0;
}
.image1, .image2 {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
.image1 h2, .image2 h2 {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

The reason it is margin-top: -14px is to compensate for the height of the h2.  14px is half of the height of h2 in the example, so adjust accordingly.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="image1">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    <h2>View Project</h2>
</div>
<div class="image2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x250" />
    <h2>View Project</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Cheers, i think i'm getting there slowly. To complicate things further, as well as all the images in the gallery being different heights and widths, some of them have text blocks of different sizes either above or below the images which are also inside the parent container. So it looks like i'll still need to set individual classes to position the h2 exactly in the centre depending on the given image itself (or should i say the size of the given container itself which contains all the different elements).